# Need Modified Code Structure for MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android

I want to insert code in **MainActivity of 'Webview' Project** To code in **MainActivity of 'Push Notification' project**.

As I'm new to Android & Java, I have spent hell lot of time but unable to produce a solution.

Suggest solution for following code structure:

> 'Push Notification' Project

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 //------Code for push notification---------------------

   }
```

> 'Webview' Project

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 //-----------Code for WebView------------

    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //----------code-----------------
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: when I inserted webviewcode its not showing error but not working as well. App crash as soon as it is started. @MehranZamani

Comment: send error log please

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution myself. Hope others find it useful.

NOTE: Put push notification code before `WebView` code else it will not run push notification.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //------Code for push notification---------------------

         //-----------Code for WebView------------

    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //----------code-----------------
        }
    }
}
```